# Auditing user-driven events in Linux

Tags: linux

Here's a scenario, a colleague has left a message that he bounced a service (restarted) because it was acting up for some reasons.

Since he is away, I can't verify directly to him which service he restarted.

How do I validate this in linux ideally with the timestamp of when the action was taken.

Comment: Did you mean say "...which *server* he restarted"?

Comment: Look into the logs. Which logs do you have depends on your flavour of "Linux" (there's quite a bit of variation).

Answer (score 1):

`uptime` will tell you how long you've been logged on.
`dmesg` can give you lots of more specific event/times - e.g.

```
dmesg -T | tail -n20
```

You can also look at various log files, or service logs:

```
journalctl -u service-name.service -b
cat /var/log/auth.log
etc...
```